# Bing Search API Azure Marketplace Authentication in c#

Tags: c#, bing-api

How can one authenticate to the `bing search api` without using the BingSearchContainer.

With **bing search container** we can do something like this:

```
   var bing = new BingSearchContainer(new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/")) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(bingKey, bingKey) };
```

But this doesn't help me because i need to pass some other proxy to access the internet.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a `WebRequest` with basic authorization.

Like this:

```
     //some demo uri
     Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Composite?Sources=%27web%27&Query=%27xbox%27&$format=json");
     System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
     byte[] byteKey = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bingKey + ":" + bingKey);
     string stringKey = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteKey);
     req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + stringKey);
     req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("proxy_url", true);
     req.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "", "");
     System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
```